# Finding node voltages in a MOSFET circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cmos

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWoxKI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Considering Vdd=5v I want to calculate the node voltages at P,Q and R.

Comment: You've entered your design into a simulator. Add a source and what does the simulator say?

Comment: Are you asking for the trivial solution, or is there more to the "circuit"?

Comment: I just want values. This is the circuit.

Comment: What i think is voltage at Q is Vdd-2Vtn. And voltage at P is Vdd-3Vtn. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

One side of this circuit is biased into saturation, and one side is in cutoff. the node voltages are a consequence of that. When Vdd is much greater than Vgs-Vtn and Vgs is much greater than Vtn, the transistor is in saturation. When Vdd is much less than Vgs-Vtn, the transistor is in cutoff. From that, you should be able to develop a sense of which ones are passing current and which ones are not.

Transistors going back and forth between saturation and cutoff without being used in the triode region may be thought of as switches. Their output voltage is either +(Vdd-Vtn) or 0 depending on their operating region.